# What's this inside my gear shift?

Tags: lights, gears

Is there a laser or something in there because it's really bright and looks weird and has a different look I'm pretty sure it isn't but it's weird .

[image: https://imgur.com/a/CG8a9v7]

Answer (score 5):

I've seen this before.  The bulb assembly usually fits into the gear indicator mechanism in a similar way that brake lights fit into brake light assemblies.  That is, usually the bulb socket has a snap tab or twist fit.  In your case the bulb is still intact but **the bulb assembly isn't in the right place**.  In other words, it's not snapped in where it's supposed to be.  It's more annoying than harmful, but I'd recommend trying to fix it anyway.

There are a number of ways of disassembling these; it varies by model, but it often involves gently prying the gear shift indicator assembly out of the housing and then snapping the bulb assembly back into place.  It will be obvious where it should be.

There's also the possibility that the last person to replace the bulb (or do some other maintenance in there) broke some plastic bit that's supposed to hold the bulb in place.  That's even more annoying, but also usually repairable buy paying a king's ransom for the replacement plastic bit, and struggling for a while to replace it, all the while cursing the clumsy gorilla mechanic who first broke it.  (Even if it's yourself!)

Answer (score 1):

Well, years ago it would be a small bulb, but now it is most likely to be an LED - some are usually colored to match the dash lights, some have colored plastic covers of some type.

Difficult to tell anything as it is on - a decent picture of the bulb / led will confirm.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it's an older car so I guess it's a small light bulb , they don't use lasers in gear shift right cuz I mean this thing is really bright to be honest

Comment: If you used a laser then you could have the selected gear info shown on the roof.... may be a mod... :)